# Use WP NFC with NFC-Enabled PC?

Tags: 8.1, nokia-lumia-1020, nfc, wireless-sync, pc

Can you use NFC between your Windows Phone 8.1 and a NFC-Enabled laptop with 8.1?

I have a Lumia 1020 w/ 8.1
& a Sony Vaio Fit 14 with 8.1

I've looked around the internet, can't find anything. I looked around on my devices and couldn't find much.

My laptop has this app thing from the sideswipe menu under Share > Windows Phone but it says "To add things to your phone, plug it into your PC with a USB cable." Meh.

It also has Devices > Tap & Send but then it says "You can only send from apps." Do I need an app, on my laptop or phone?

So, is NFC between the two impossible? If so, what are its capabilities?

TIA :)

Comment: what exactely are you trying to do with NFC? be aware that NFC is only used for either sending very small amounts of data like a command to open an app or for example to pair two phones. Bigger file transfers like photos are done through bluetooth after NFC pairing.

Comment: As Thomas said, file transfers are done via Bluetooth - not NFC. NFC is a standard way of communicating (like voice, light etc) but there are kind of no standards of what language should be used (that's why wp and android doesn't like communicating so often). So in order for the two different devices to communicate they need to use a common language. The language is often app specific.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, phone and pcs can communicate via NFC, though the app developer must enable this.

For example, I made an app that farted when an NFC laptop touched an NFC phone.

Answer (score 1):

NFC (or RFID) is a low bandwidth serial connection, the same that's used in conventional smart card readers to communicate with cards; there is no standard protocol to send files on it and even if there was, the bandwidth is too low to be usable.

If you want to experiment you can create a small "echo server" app that displays and sends back whatever data it receives via NFC, and create a client app on the computer that sends data (on computers, NFC appears as a smart card reader and you use the same APIs - PC/SC, etc), your client app should display the data you send from the computer.